# How to see C# library code like grepcode is for Java?

Tags: c#

New to C# family. When I want to see the Java library code, I generally use grepcode.com. How can I see the code for C# libraries.

```
For ex: Code for ArrayList.Sort() method?
```

Comment: well, the .NET Framework is open source so you can go to github and take a look or even here really: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Nice link. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'll can find the source code for .Net in C# at:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com

This will let you navigate through name spaces, or search for particular classes.